# Добавить несколько значений в словарь по одному ключу

Tags: python, python-2.x

Доброе время суток, я новенький в этом деле, по этому, прошу о помощи.
Необходимо добавить в словарь несколько значений по одному ключу, `dict.update()` и `dict.setdefault()` пробовал - не вышло.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Попробуйте `defaultdict` из модуля `collections`:

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(list)

d[1].append(1)
d[1].append(2)
d[1].append(3)

d[2].append(1)
d[2].append(1)
d[2].append(1)

print d[1]
print d[2]
```

---

Если использовать только стандартный словарь, то нужно проверять значение по ключу и добавлять вручную, что-то вроде такого:

```
d = dict()
if 1 not in d:
    d[1] = list()

d[1].append(1)
d[1].append(2)
d[1].append(3)

if 2 not in d:
    d[2] = list()

d[2].append(1)
d[2].append(1)
d[2].append(1)

print d[1]
print d[2]
```

Comment: Разве в Python 2.7 уже есть collections?

Comment: @Denis, а у вас нет или вы код не запускали? А так: https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html

Comment: Прошу прощения, все работает, а что значит: d = defaultdict(list)

Comment: @Denis, создание словаря с конструктором объекта по умолчанию, для данного случая это `list`, При добавлении нового ключа, этот конструтор будет вызван (туда можно и функции подсовывать). если был бы 'dict', т.е. `d = defaultdict(dict)`, то можно было писать такое: `d[1][2] = 3`. Поставьте что ответ подходит :)

Answer (score 1):

Реализация через `setdefault`:

```
from __future__ import print_function
from random import randint

d = dict()

for _ in range(10):
    key = randint(0, 3)
    value = randint(0, 10)
    d.setdefault(key, []).append(value)

print(d)
```

Пример вывода:

```
{0: [3], 3: [7, 1, 6, 10, 9], 2: [4, 4, 6], 1: [0]}
```

Как это работает:

`setdefault` проверяет, есть ли значение по указанному ключу, если нет - то записывает указанное дефолтное значение (в данном случае пустой список) в словарь по этому ключу, и его же возвращает, либо возвращает существующее значение из словаря.

Можно примерно представить как функцию:

```
def setdefault(d, key, value):
    if key not in d:
        d[key] = value
    
    return d[key]
```

Решение через `setdefault` не очень красивое и не оптимальное (на каждый вызов `setdefault` создается экземпляр пустого списка), лучше использовать вариант с `defaultdict`.

Преимущества `defautldict`:

- не нужен отдельный метод, все работает через обычный синтаксис получения значения из словаря (я каждый раз заново вспоминаю, как там этот `setdefault` работает, а тут вспоминать ничего не нужно)
- дефолтный объект (список в данном случае) не создается сразу, а только при необходимости (при отсутствии ключа вызывается переданная в `defaultdict` функция-фабрика значений).

Соответствующий код через `defaultdict`:

```
from __future__ import print_function
from collections import defaultdict
from random import randint

d = defaultdict(list)

for _ in range(10):
    key = randint(0, 3)
    value = randint(0, 10)
    d[key].append(value)

print(d)
```